# how can I use bash to blacklist processes such as sharingd?

Tags: bash, macos

I am attempting to use bash to permanently kill the process sharingd.

I have tried using the command "sudo kill -9 (pid of port sharingd is using)", but sharingd just reopens on another port.

lsof -i

sudo kill -9 PID

My expected results should stop sharingd from running, but it just uses a different port each time.

Pardon my inability to display my code as actual code, I am somewhat new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's probably being restarted by `launchd`. You need to unload the launch daemon.

Comment: `sharingd` is used by services like AirDrop. Why don't you just turn off the services that use it? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285945/what-are-the-sharingd-and-sharedfilelistd-processes

Comment: It looks like this can't be unloaded. When I tried, I got `Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged`

Comment: Thanks ... If figured out how to use launchctl, but how can I find the path to sharingd?

Comment: It's `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.sharingd.plist`.

Comment: In general, system-wide launchctl files live in `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

Comment: I searched all of them for something with `sharingd`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do it, but I got the error you stated above about System Integrity. Can this be fixed with sudo? If so, will it actually compromise my "System Integrity"?

Comment: No, even the superuser can't get around SIP -- that's what makes it so safe. You have to boot into single-user mode to disable it. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x